# Custom variable index inside a DJango template

Tags: django, templates

I have a template in Django that is generated by a for loop like

```
{% for test in test_list %}

   <!-- dome code here -->
    {% if not test.testInPausa %}
    <div class="progress-wrapper-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
      <div
        id="progress-bar-{{ forloop.counter0 }}"
        class="progress-bar-{{ forloop.counter0 }} progress-bar-striped"
      >
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="progress-bar-message-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
      Waiting for progress to start...
    </div>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

Now, I would like to count the time in which the code enter the if statement.

I want to do so because, at the moment, the id and class inside the div are indexed by the forloop.counter, which, because it doesn't always enter the if statement, counts every for loop making the id and class jump index.

Is there a way to have something

```
{% my_index = 0 %}
{% for test in test_list %}
       <!-- dome code here -->
        {% if not test.testInPausa %}
        <div class="progress-wrapper-{{ my_index }}">
          <div
            id="progress-bar-{{ my_index }}"
            class="progress-bar-{{ my_index }} progress-bar-striped"
          >
            &nbsp;
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="progress-bar-message-{{ my_index }}">
          Waiting for progress to start...
        </div>
{% my_index++ %}
        {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

I've tried the `with` statement and the [builtin add filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add) with no luck

```
{% with count=0 %}
    {% for test in test_list %}
           <!-- dome code here -->
            {% if not test.testInPausa %}
            <div class="progress-wrapper-{{ my_index }}">
              <div
                id="progress-bar-{{ my_index }}"
                class="progress-bar-{{ my_index }} progress-bar-striped"
              >
                &nbsp;
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress-bar-message-{{ my_index }}">
              Waiting for progress to start...
            </div>
    {{ count|add:"1" }} {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `forloop.counter` rather than trying to maintain your own.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Edit: Do the `if` in the view so that `test_list` contains only the things you want iterated over. This is not logic that should be in a template. Then use `forloop.counter`

Comment: as explained, I need to count the time that the cycle enters the `if`, not the total number o cycles

Comment: That logic doesn't belong in a template.

Comment: According to Django doc it should be done in the template as well tho

Comment: I think you've discovered why this shouldn't be done in the template, and I would advise against it. Just send the correct data to the template to start with - do the filtering in the views. I doubt django docs tell you to do what you're doing becuase it's business logic in the display layer.

Comment: the only solution was to elaborate things in the backend